# Flutter Pub Cache Error build gradle error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/D:/flutter_3.0.5/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.4.1/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'.
FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_delegate);
^^^^^^
lib/screens/kilofarmsWebview.dart:22:13: Error: The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the class 'KilofarmsWebview'.

- 'KilofarmsWebview' is from 'package:ruby/screens/kilofarmsWebview.dart' ('lib/screens/kilofarmsWebview.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'.
  How to Solve this error. i was run my another laptop build gradle works fine. but my current system not worked in build gradle. but both are same setup.

How to Solve this error. i was run my another laptop build gradle works fine. but my current system not worked in build gradle. but both are same setup.